# map each vector element to a vector

Tags: daru

I use Daru and have a vector.

```rb
vector = Daru::Vector.new({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

Now, I have a function which I'd like to apply on each element and obtain result as vector.

```rb
// example function; a function I'd like to apply on each element
f = ->(num) { rand(num) }

vector.some_mapping_method(&f)
# => expects Vector of { a: rand(1), b: rand(2), c: rand(3) }
```

I tried `.map` method, but that returns result in an array.

## Question

How can I map each element in a vector and return a vector, which has the same index as the original one?

In python terms, I want `.map` method of `pd.Series` in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `map!` and `recode` methods for `Vector` (see [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daru/Daru/Vector#map!-instance_method))

So, you should be able to do either:
`vector.map! {|value| rand(value)}`
or
`new_vector = vector.recode {|value| rand(value)}`
(or `vector = vector.recode {|value| rand(value)}` if you want to change your vector in place)

*I used `recode` in my code, not `map!`, so I don't guarantee it works this way. Documentation on `map!` is not the best*